# Splitting a pairwise matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix in the following way:

```
         gene ids  A-B   A-C  A-D  B-C  B-D C-D

          GENE1     0     0    1    1    1   0
          GENE2     1     0    1    1    1   1
          GENE3     1     0    0    0    1   1
          GENE4     0     1    0    0    0   0
```

and would like to split it as follows:The diagonal values will be empty because the above matrix is a pairwise comparison.

```
          Gene1
               A  B   C  D  
           A      0   0  1 
           B   0      1  1
           C   0  1      0
           D   1  1   0
```

In the same way for all the genes.

I have more than 10000 genes and cannot do it manually. I tried several things but didn work.

Comment: Can we assume the order of the columns is the way as above?

Comment: Yes the order is the same but there are a number of columns ( more than 50).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I build on the answer of MrGumble above. The problem with his solution is that R always has its entries ordered column-major, thus we may fill the lower triangle with the column of data, but not the upper triangle. One easy way is just to use the lower part, or to fill the upper part of the matrix with the transpose of the lower.

```
m <- structure(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(4L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("GENE1", "GENE2", "GENE3", "GENE4"), c("A-B", "A-C", "A-D", "B-C", "B-D", "C-D")))

gene <- matrix(0, ncol=4, nrow=4) # empty, template matrix
gene[lower.tri(gene)] <- m[4,]
gene <- gene + t(gene)
diag(gene) <- NA
```

(Made this community wiki, as it is not totally my own answer).

Answer (score 2):

```
m <- structure(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(4L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("GENE1", "GENE2", "GENE3", "GENE4"), c("A-B", "A-C", "A-D", "B-C", "B-D", "C-D")))

gene <- matrix(NA, ncol=4, nrow=4) # empty, template matrix
gene[upper.tri(gene)] <- m[1,]
gene[lower.tri(gene)] <- rev(m[1,])

## gene now contains the interaction matrix for GENE1.
```

Comment: Close, but not totally true. Suppose gene5 would be `c(0,0,1, 0,0,0)`. Then your matrix is not symmetric anymore.

Comment: Good grief, thank you for catching it @Thilo. I have added a ``rev`` to clear it.

Comment: `rev` won't do it, see `c(1,0,0,0,0,0)`. See my answer below.

Comment: I've been living me entire life on a lie. :(